# Names of columns change from CSV to R: dot instead of slash

Tags: r, csv

When I inport a CSV file in R the names of the columns change. They go from "Fe/Cu" to "Fe.Cu". But I have this mysterious problem only with one CSV file.
I tried to rename the columns

```
colnames(a[12:ncol(a)])=c("Fe/Cu","Fe/Zn","Fe/Ba")
```

But nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `check.names=FALSE` in the `read.csv` function call.

Comment: Note that it's better to have columns as syntactically valid.

From documentation: A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the reserved words.

Otherwise you have to reference to your columns using backquotes, which might be frustrating. Like a$'Fe/Cu' (it's actually backquotes like backticks here) instead of a$Fe.Cu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `check.names=FALSE` to `csv.read` function call will allow you to get the original names. This is because by default `csv.read` will check if column names are syntactically valid as stated by @Asayat in the commets.

From `csv.read` documentation:

> check.names - logical: If TRUE then the names of the variables in the
>   data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid
>   variable names. If necessary they are adjusted (by make.names) so that
>   they are, and also to ensure that there are no duplicates.

If you then check for the documentation of `make.names` you will find:

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the
>   reserved words.

which is what @Asayat commented.

Answer (score 0):

Column indexes should be after `colnames` like below:

```
colnames(a)[12:ncol(a)]=c("Fe/Cu","Fe/Zn","Fe/Ba")
```